# Proof of central limit theorem without using MGF or characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

The proofs of central limit theorem(CLT) I have seen all use moment generating function (MGF) or characteristic functions.

For special situations, for example, the summation of independent normal distributed random variables, is there a proof of CLT without using MGF or characteristic functions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Terence Tao's Blog post gives a general results of different proofs of CLT: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/275a-notes-4-the-central-limit-theorem/

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just answering to the example you give, which is straightforward: if $X_n$, $n\in\mathbb N^*$ are i.i.d. with distribution $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$,
$$
\sqrt n\frac{\frac1n(X_1+\cdots+X_n)-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal N(0,1),
$$
so its distribution not only converges to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ but is constant equal to it.

Comment: to prove the statement in your answer, do we need MGF or characteristic function ? or can we prove the statement without using MGF or characteristic function ? That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Nothing of the sort. You can easily prove that the sum of two independent gaussian variables is gaussian. Then an immediate induction gives you that the sum of $n$ independent gaussian variables is gaussian. So the left-hand side I wrote above is gaussian, and you can easily compute its mean and standard deviation, namely $0$ and $1$ respectively. That's all.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration.